# Maximize the probability of success to pass the exam

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As part of her computer science studies, Sam has to complete a mathematics examination. In the test, both simple and difficult tasks are set up. The probability of solving a simple problem is $ e $. A difficult task is usually solved with probability $ s $, where $ s <e $. Sam has to deal with three tasks to pass the exam. The tasks must be processed in the given order. Sam has the choice between easy-difficult-easy and difficult-easy-difficult. The test is passed if Sam successfully processes two consecutive tasks. It is assumed that the three tasks are processed successfully independently of each other. Which order should Sam choose to maximize the probability of success to pass the exam?

$$$$

We have to calculate the possibilities $P(\text{easy-difficult-easy})$ and $P(\text{difficult-easy-difficult})$, or not?

$P(\text{easy-difficult-easy})$ means that $P(\text{easy }\land \text{ difficult } \land \text{ easy})$ and since each of the is solved independently we get that $$P(\text{easy }\land \text{ difficult } \land \text{ easy})=P(\text{easy })\cdot P( \text{ difficult } )\cdot P(\text{ easy})=e\cdot s\cdot e=e^2\cdot s$$

Is that correct?

Is the other possibility then the following?

\begin{align*}P(\text{difficult-easy-difficult})&=P(\text{difficult }\land \text{easy }\land \text{ difficult}) \\ & =P( \text{difficult } )\cdot P(\text{ easy })\cdot P( \text{ difficult } ) \\ & =s\cdot e\cdot s=s^2\cdot e\end{align*}

Comment: Well, you defined success as passing two trials in a row but you calculated the probability of passing all three.  Surely you want to include the cases where Sam gets the first two right but not the third, or gets the first wrong and the second two right.

Comment: Informally, intuition would say dificult-easy-difficult was better since the "must answer" question is then easy.  Granted, intuition doesn't always work well in probability.

Comment: Ah ok! We have the case: pass - pass - pass , pass - pass - fail, pass - fail - pass, fail - pass - pass 

Therefore, we get \begin{align*}P(\text{easy }\land \text{ difficult } \land \text{ easy})&=P(\text{easy })\cdot P( \text{ difficult } )\cdot P(\text{ easy}) \\ & = e\cdot s\cdot e+e\cdot s\cdot (1-e)+e\cdot (1-s)\cdot e+(1-e)\cdot s\cdot e\end{align*} @lulu

Comment: And for the other case we get :  

\begin{align*}P(\text{difficult }\land \text{easy }\land \text{ difficult})& =P( \text{difficult } )\cdot P(\text{ easy })\cdot P( \text{ difficult } ) \\ & =s\cdot e\cdot s+s\cdot e\cdot (1-s)+s\cdot (1-e)\cdot s+(1-s)\cdot e\cdot s\end{align*} 

Is that correct? @lulu

Comment: Well, I am unclear as to your notation.  Also as to your algebra.  Let's do Difficult-easy-difficult.  Then the probability of success is $ses +se(1-s)+(1-s)es=se + se(1-s)$.  Yes?  First term is "all three right"  second is "first two right, third wrong"  third is "first wrong, second two right".  For Easy-difficult-easy the same reasoning yields $es+es(1-e)$ and it is then easy, I think, to see that intuition is upheld.

Comment: Ahh ok!! We have that $e$ is the probability that the task is easy. Does it hold that $1-e=s$, i.e., that the probability that it is not easy is equal to the probability that it is difficult? @lulu

Comment: I don't see why you'd conclude that.

Comment: So the complementary of easy is not necessary difficult, is it? So $1-e$ means thst it is not easy, but it can be of normal difficulty and nt dufficult? @lulu

Comment: It's your problem.  Nothing in your phrasing suggests that there is any preset relation between $e$ and $s$ other than $e>s$.  I have posted something below, perhaps it helps.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! @lulu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand the problem, success is defined by getting two questions in a row right.  Thus to succeed Sam has to get the middle one right, so I think intuition would suggest that Sam wants the middle one to be easy.  Let's check that.

Easy-Difficult-Easy:

Probability of getting all three right: $ese$

Probability of getting the first two right, third wrong:  $es(1-e)$

Probability of getting the first wrong, second two right:  $(1-e)se$.

So:  the success probability is $$ese+2es(1-e)=es+es(1-e)=es(2-e)$$

Difficult-Easy-Difficult

Probability of getting all three right: $ses$

Probability of getting the first two right, third wrong:  $se(1-s)$

Probability of getting the first wrong, second two right:  $(1-s)es$.

So:  the success probability is $$ses+2se(1-s)=se+se(1-s)=se(2-s)$$

Since $e>s\implies 2-s>2-e$ we see that the success probability is higher for Difficult-easy-difficult, confirming the intuition.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, note that in order to correctly solve "two consecutive tasks", you must solve the middle task, and then either the first or last (or both) as well. In other words, you must pass the middle task and not fail both other tasks.

Probability of success if you choose hard-easy-hard: $e(1-(1-s)^2)$

$(1-s)$ represents failing the hard task, and you must not do this twice in a row. Failing it twice in a row occurs with probability $(1-s)^2$, so probability that you do not do this is $1-(1-s)^2$. Multiply by $e$ since you *must* pass the easy middle task.

Probability of success if you choose easy-hard-easy: $s(1-(1-e)^2)$

$(1-e)$ represents failing the easy task, and you must not do this twice in a row. Failing it twice in a row occurs with probability $(1-e)^2$, so probability that you do not do this is $1-(1-e)^2$. Multiply by $s$ since you *must* pass the hard middle task.

Now, to the question: which is greater? Just choose a simple example where $s < e$. If $e=1$ and $s=0.5$, your probability of success with easy-hard-easy is $0.5$ and your probability of success with hard-easy-hard is $0.75$ Therefore, you should choose hard-easy-hard.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

If a pass for two consecutive right answers:

$1)$ Easy-hard-easy: 
$$P(SSF)+P(FSS)=es(1-e)+(1-e)se=2es(1-e).$$
$2)$ Hard-easy-hard:
$$P(SSF)+P(FSS)=se(1-s)+(1-s)es=2es(1-s)>2es(1-e).$$

If a pass for any two right answers:

$1)$ Easy-hard-easy:
$$P(SSF)+P(SFS)+P(FSS)=es(1-e)+e(1-s)e+(1-e)se=e^2(1-3s)+2es.$$
$2)$ Hard-easy-hard:
$$P(SSF)+P(SFS)+P(FSS)=se(1-s)+s(1-e)s+(1-s)es=s^2(1-3e)+2se<e^2(1-3s)+2es.$$

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)